# Protractor compare string numbers

Tags: string, numbers, compare, jasmine, protractor

Today I've faced interesting problem of create test for pretty simple behavior: *'Most recent'* sorting. All what test need to know:

1. Every item have ID
2. Previous ID is less then next in this case of sorting

**Approach**: writing ID in to attribute of item, getting that id from first item with `getAttribute()` and either way for second.

**Problem**: `getAttribute()` promise resulting with string value and Jasmine is not able to compare (from the box) string numbers.

I would like to find elegant way to compare them with `toBeLessThan()` instead of using chains of few `.then()` that will be finished with comparing that things.

[Root of no-type-definition evil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Zj7.png)

Thanks guys <3

Comment: can't you just coerce your strings to numbers, like : `expect(+itemId).toBeLessThan(+anotherItemId);` ?

Comment: You probably don't know, but any jasmine method returning Promise object that can be used by expecting method. In your case +itemId equals +Object. Anyway tnx for idea.

Comment: Yes but object may have a `.toString()` or `.valueOf()` method that allow the coercion.

Comment: Surely, but Promise Object to string will return weird thing :D

Comment: May be the same but have you tried with `Number(itemId);` ? In both case this will return `NaN` if it fails to coerce the result, is that what you get ?

Comment: Surely, Number() with Promise as param returns NaN and that one of cases why I'm looking for another way to do comparing.

Comment: Another way maybe, can't you modify values before evaluation by storing them into variables and parsing them ? :/

Comment: Already found solution, similar to your guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot of native nature of promises but tnx to Michael Radionov I've remembered what I want to do.

```
expect(first.then( r => Number(r) )).toBe(next.then( r => Number(r) ));
```

I guess this stroke looks simple.

**UPDATE**

ES6:

```
it('should test numbers', async function () {
    let first = Number(await $('#first').getText());
    let second = Number(await $('#second').getText());
    expect(first).toBeGreaterThan(second);
})
```

Comment: Not using + either !! to stay clean.

Comment: Actually `+` is considered as an explicit coercion, once you know it, it's pretty clean as long as you don't use it in the middle of another computation.

Comment: I write code that will be used as examples for juniors :D

Answer (score 4):

You can create a helper function to convert string number to actual number, which will make use of Promises:

```
function toNumber(promiseOrValue) {

    // if it is not a promise, then convert a value
    if (!protractor.promise.isPromise(promiseOrValue)) {
        return parseInt(promiseOrValue, 10);
    }

    // if promise - convert result to number
    return promiseOrValue.then(function (stringNumber) {
        return parseInt(stringNumber, 10);
    });
}
```

And then use the result with `.toBeLessThan`, etc:

```
expect(toNumber(itemId)).toBeLessThan(toNumber(anotherItemId));
```

Comment: Yea, I like this one, probably will use, but in this case i need to create separate file with some mixins that will be related to tests. Probably it will be easier to find out is there any npm module that can be imported for that way. Maybe you know any that already do such converting?

Comment: I am not sure that there is a separate module just to convert string to number. I agree, it looks a bit ugly, but if you use Page Objects, you could embed this conversion into their methods, so specs will remain clean.

Comment: Anyway this made me remember what actually I'm trying to do. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

One option to approach it with a *custom jasmine matcher*:

```
toBeSorted: function() {
    return {
        compare: function(actual) {
            var expected = actual.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
                return +a.localeCompare(+b);
            });

            return {
                pass: jasmine.matchersUtil.equals(actual, expected)
            };
        }
    };
},
```

Here the matcher takes an actual input array, integer-sort it and compare with the input array.

Usage:

```
expect(element.all(by.css(".myclass")).getAttribute("id")).toBeSorted();
```

Note that here we are calling `getAttribute("id")` on an `ElementArrayFinder` which would resolve into an array of `id` attribute values. `expect()` itself is patched to implicitly resolve promises.

Comment: Not sure about sorting matcher, but I guess some special comparence or prematcher (like .not) will be created. I will do something like .enum.toBeGreaterThan(). At least I would not be forced to bother with that promises. Tnx bud.