# How do you parseInt or stringify values in protractor.js?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to use [protractor.js](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) and I can't seem to compare a string to an integer without getting an error like    `Expected '4' to equal 'ManagedPromise::1428 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}'.`

```
  it('should equal', function() {
    
      var n = $('#total').getAttribute('value') //returns '4'
      var rows = element.all(by.repeater('service in services')); // returns 4 

      //var rowCount = rows.count().toString()
      expect(n).toEqual(rows.count()) //'4' != 4 .... I want it to match 
       
   });
```

How do I make an integer a string or vice versa?

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
function toNumber(promiseOrValue) {
    // if it is not a promise, then convert a value
    if (!protractor.promise.isPromise(promiseOrValue)) {
        return parseInt(promiseOrValue, 10);
    }
    // if promise - convert result to number
    return promiseOrValue.then(function (stringNumber) {
        return parseInt(stringNumber, 10);
    });
}
```

from [Protractor compare string numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479390/protractor-compare-string-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

I would convert them both to int then compare:

```
expect(n.then( v => parseInt(v))).toEqual(rows.count().then( v => parseInt(v)))
// getAttribute and count both return promises
```